# Java set DateFormat timezone to GMT+1

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

What is the correct string to set the DateFormat timezone to GMT+1?
According the documentation it should be something like "GMT + 00:00".
I already tried other forms but apparently I always fallback to GMT (my current timezone).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find whole set of time zones via following fragment of code:

```
for (String id : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

And reuse it to set timezone directly:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(id));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
TimeZone fixedUtcPlus1 = new SimpleTimeZone(TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1),
                                            "GMT+1");
format.setTimeZone(fixedUtcPlus1);
```

Or just:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1");
format.setTimeZone(zone);
```

(Apologies for the repeated edits around +1 and -1... bad diagnostics on my part. "GMT+1" is fine, but its Etc equivalent is "Etc/GMT-1" - very confusing.)

Comment: SimpleTimeZone constructor accepts only an int, not a long, so I'd say  new SimpleTimeZone((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1), "GMT+1"); would be more correct.
...
And thanks for the explanation that Etc/GMT-1 is actually GMT+1. That weird stuff made me wonder whether I was doing something wrong myself for days now! :)